# issue in understanding in `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function` in node

Tags: node.js

i am new to node and having issue in understanding why this error `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function` is occurs
by running the command `node file-create-directory.js`

`file-create-directory.js` file is:

```
const fs = require('fs');
if(!fs.exists('views')){
  fs.mkdir('views',(err) =>{
    if(err) return err;
    fs.writeFile('./views/new.html','this is a new directory and data', (err) =>{
       if(err) return err;
        console.log('Directory and file saved');
    });
  });    
}
```

Comment: What line does your error point to in the stacktrace

Comment: This error is basically occurring because you didn't pass any callback function in the `fs.exists` in the second argument. And you should use the solution provided by @elraphty

Answer (score 2):

First of all `fs.exists` is deprecated

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.access('views', fs.constants.F_OK, (err) => {
  // if it does not exists
  if(err) {
     fs.mkdir('views', (err) => {
       if(!err) { 
         fs.writeFile('./views/new.html', 'this is a new directory and data', 
         (err) => {
           if(err) return err;
           console.log('Directory and file saved');
         }
     });
  }
});
```

But if you decide to use `fs.exists` use this

```
fs.exists('views', (exists) => {
  if(!exists) {
     fs.mkdir('views',(err) => {
       if(err) return err;
       fs.writeFile('./views/new.html','this is a new directory and 
       data', (err) => {
         if(err) return err;
         console.log('Directory and file saved');
       });
     });  
  }
});
```

Comment: Where is this fs file? been looking all over for it. I get this when I do a mvn clean install. How do I change it?